# MainMenu control not displaying underlining when using & and pressing ALT

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I'm using a MainMenu control (not MenuStrip) in a WinForm. In design view I can put an & in the text field and it will display the underlining but when the program is running and I press ALT it does not appear.

Also for some reason the '&' character is actually drawn (e.g. &File) to the display when used on the top level.

Has anyone had this problem before and solved it? I've searched around and haven't found a solution except for drawing my own but this seems like a problem that should be solvable since it's a built in feature of the control.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Obviously the underline doesn't show up because the & is still visible.  Why is unguessable, this behavior is implemented by Windows, not by .NET code.  Don't write &&File.

Comment: The only explanation that makes sense to me is that your caption is &&File

Comment: @Hans It's only drawn at the top level of the menu. Sub menus do not show the & character. I'm not writing &&... The problem is underlining does not appear when the ALT key is pressed and it should do.

Comment: There is a **UseMnemonics** property for buttons, labels etc. which allows you to control whether _"&"_ character would translate to a literal or shortcut key. Check if this setting is there for either the Form/MainMenu/MenuItem and set it to true. That may solve your problem.

Comment: There was some compiled external GUI extensions at play which was overriding rendering of the menu. Suspected this at first but thought it was in the source code but I then got round to checking the extension references and checked some of their methods where I noticed an override which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Form.MainMenu` set to your `MainMenu`?

For SubMenuItems also check the relevant windows settings: In WinXp it is under Display Properties / Appearance / Effects on XP

Comment: Yeah. It's not appearing when ALT is pressed. Those settings are to make underlining visible all the time. The underlining does not appear at all even though in design view I have added the underlining and is visible there. Is MainMenu a legacy control or something? Because it does not appear under the tools pane in VS (only MenuStrip) it got me thinking perhaps it is not possible with this control if it is pre XP.

Comment: No, MainMenu was supported in .Net 1.x and 2.x if I remember correctly. Now it is recommended to use `MenuStrip` but it is still 100% fine to use `MainMenu` for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the items in the menu have the properties
 `ShowShortCutKeys = true.`